# Changing color scheme of plotly express plot. (Choroplot)

Tags: python, express, plot, plotly, choropleth

simple yet wasted lots of times trying to do this.
i would like to change the color_continuous_scale="ylgn", attribute of the fig = px.choropleth_mapbox plot. The plot works but when i click my drop down buttons it doesnt change at all when i try the dropdown buttons, not to Temps or any of the other built in color scales, (last 2 of dropdown are more for testing) how can i change the colorscale ( by using my dropdown buttons) from ylgn to temps or any other like viridis gray halin ....?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='unemp',
                           color_continuous_scale="ylgn",
                           range_color=(0, 12),
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=3, center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
                           opacity=0.5,
                           labels={'unemp':'unemployment rate'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})





fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="1",
                     method="update",
                     args=["colorscale", "ylgn"]),
                dict(label="2",
                     method="update",
                     args=["colorscale", "temps"]),
                dict(label="3",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"range_color": (0, 500)}]),
                dict(label="4",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"range_color": (0, 500)}]),
            ]),
        )
    ])

# Set title
fig.update_layout(title_text="Map of the USA")

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a basic map with a graph object, you can switch the colormap by buttons. I have no reason to explain why this cannot be done in Express. The button to toggle the colormap in the [references](https://plotly.com/python/custom-buttons/#restyle-button) goes back to the first colormap set, but in my environment (jupyterlab) it does not go back to the default colormap.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=counties, locations=df.fips, z=df.unemp,
                                    colorscale="ylgn", zmin=0, zmax=12,
                                    marker_opacity=0.5, marker_line_width=0))
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                  mapbox_zoom=3, mapbox_center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129})

fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":30,"l":0,"b":0})

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="ylgn",
                     method="restyle",
                     args=["colorscale", "ylgn"]),
                dict(label="temps",
                     method="restyle",
                     args=["colorscale", "temps"]),
            ]),
            showactive=True,
            #type='buttons'
        )
    ])

# Set title
fig.update_layout(title_text="Map of the USA")

fig.show()
```

[image]